# ONNXRuntimeError : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcurand.so.10

Tags: tensorflow, onnxruntime, yolov7

`ONNX Failed to create CUDAExecutionProvider.`

Environment: venv on Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10

GPU: Quadro P600 driver 535

cuda 11.8, cudnn 8.6, & cudnn 8.9 are installed correctly on the system.

Packages installed:

```
absl-py==2.0.0
apturl==0.5.2
astunparse==1.6.3
bcrypt==3.2.0
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.8.3
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
coloredlogs==15.0.1
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==3.4.8
cuda-python==11.8.0
cupshelpers==1.0
Cython==3.0.5
dbus-python==1.2.18
defer==1.0.6
distro==1.7.0
distro-info==1.1+ubuntu0.1
duplicity==0.8.21
fasteners==0.14.1
filelock==3.9.0
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fsspec==2023.4.0
future==0.18.2
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.23.4
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.59.3
h5py==3.10.0
httplib2==0.20.2
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.6.4
jeepney==0.7.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
keras==2.14.0
keyring==23.5.0
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
libclang==16.0.6
lockfile==0.12.2
louis==3.20.0
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
Mako==1.1.3
Markdown==3.5.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
ml-dtypes==0.2.0
monotonic==1.6
more-itertools==8.10.0
mpmath==1.3.0
netifaces==0.11.0
networkx==3.0
numpy==1.24.3
nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.11.3.6
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.8.87
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu11==11.8.89
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.8.89
nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.7.0.84
nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11==10.3.0.86
nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.1.48
nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.5.86
nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.16.5
oauthlib==3.2.0
olefile==0.46
onnxruntime-gpu==1.16.3
opencv-python==4.8.1.78
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.2
paramiko==2.9.3
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==9.0.1
protobuf==4.25.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycairo==1.20.1
pycups==2.0.1
PyGObject==3.42.1
PyJWT==2.3.0
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyRFC3339==1.1
python-apt==2.4.0+ubuntu2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-debian==0.1.43+ubuntu1.1
pytz==2022.1
pyxdg==0.27
PyYAML==5.4.1
reportlab==3.6.8
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
SecretStorage==3.3.1
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.12
systemd-python==234
tensorboard==2.14.1
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.14.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.14.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.34.0
tensorrt==8.5.3.1
termcolor==2.3.0
torch==2.1.1+cu118
torchaudio==2.1.1+cu118
torchvision==0.16.1+cu118
triton==2.1.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools==8001
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36.1
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.26.5
usb-creator==0.3.7
wadllib==1.3.6
Werkzeug==3.0.1
wrapt==1.14.1
```

Error message I get:

```
2023-11-22 18:34:08.959317292 [E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1480 TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1193 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

2023-11-22 18:34:08.959328586 [W:onnxruntime:Default, onnxruntime_pybind_state.cc:747 CreateExecutionProviderInstance] Failed to create CUDAExecutionProvider. Please reference https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements to ensure all dependencies are met.
```

To reproduce:

```py
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorrt
import onnxruntime as ort
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print(ort.get_device())
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
cuda = True
providers = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'] if cuda else ['CPUExecutionProvider']
w = "yolov7.onnx"
session = ort.InferenceSession(w, providers=providers)
outputs_labels = session.get_outputs()[0].name
inputs_names = session.get_inputs()[0].name
```

The print statements output respectively is:

```py
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
GPU
True
```

`libcurand.so.10` exists in its path in cuda installation files.

I don't know why I get this error. I tried:

1. Reinstalling cuda and cudnn
2. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for CUDA
3. Reinstalling onnxruntime-gpu
4. Trying the code with and without importing torch
5. Trying the code with and without importing tensorflow
6. Making new clean venv and just install onnxruntime-gpu and opencv-python and trying the code.

All this did not work for me.

I expect the problem is because of some package's compatibility issues. But I can't figure it out. I made sure to install everything to be compatible.

Comment: I've been encountering the same error when trying to launch a CUDA inference session in onnxruntime-gpu using WSL Debian. Installation seems correct and referenced in Path, no conflicting installs, detected in PyTorch, yet fails once invoked. Messing with versions and reinstalls and attempts in Windows have yielded no results.

Comment: I solved this by installing cuDNN through conda and adding its library to Path